# How to upgrade nginx on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: upgrade, nginx

We are currently running nginx on ubuntu, installed version is:
`1.10.3-0ubuntu0.16.04.3`

Running `sudo apt update` it reflects that we are on the latest version, however going to nginx.org shows the latest version is 1.17.

How do we upgrade to the latest version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Follow the instructions on the Nginx website:

http://nginx.org/en/linux_packages.html#Ubuntu

> Install the prerequisites:
>
> `sudo apt install curl gnupg2 ca-certificates lsb-release`
>
> To set up the apt repository for stable nginx packages, run the following command:
>
> ```
> echo "deb http://nginx.org/packages/ubuntu `lsb_release -cs` nginx" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nginx.list
> ```
>
> If you would like to use mainline nginx packages, run the following command instead:
>
> ```
> echo "deb http://nginx.org/packages/mainline/ubuntu `lsb_release -cs` nginx" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nginx.list
> ```
>
> Next, import an official nginx signing key so apt could verify the packages
>   authenticity:
>
> ```
> curl -fsSL https://nginx.org/keys/nginx_signing.key | sudo apt-key add -
> ```
>
> Verify that you now have the proper key:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-key fingerprint ABF5BD827BD9BF62
> ```
>
> The output should contain the full fingerprint `573B FD6B 3D8F BC64 1079 A6AB ABF5 BD82 7BD9 BF62` as follows:
>
> ```
> pub   rsa2048 2011-08-19 [SC] [expires: 2024-06-14]
>       573B FD6B 3D8F BC64 1079  A6AB ABF5 BD82 7BD9 BF62
> uid   [ unknown] nginx signing key <signing-key@nginx.com>
> ```
>
> To install nginx,
>   run the following commands:
>
> ```
> sudo apt update
> sudo apt install nginx
> ```

Comment: Errors were encountered while processing: /var/cache/apt/archives/nginx_1.18.0-2~xenial_amd64.deb

Comment: nginx: [emerg] module "/etc/nginx/modules/ngx_http_dav_ext_module.so" version 1016001 instead of 1018000 in /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-dav-ext.conf:1 nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is, Compile Nignx yourself. It will give you the latest updated version.

Compiled packages are not always the updated version, But they focus on the stable version.

Answer (score 0):

Follow below commands from the terminal.

`cd /tmp`

`wget http://nginx.org/keys/nginx_signing.key`

`sudo apt-key add nginx_signing.key`

`sudo sh -c "echo 'deb http://nginx.org/packages/stable/ubuntu/ '$(lsb_release -cs)' nginx' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/Nginx.list"`

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

Comment: After doing this I still get the same version?